# curl: Accessing a TLS secured FTP server through a proxy

Tags: ssl, curl, proxy, ftp

I'm trying to connect to a FTP server which requires TLS1.2 through a proxy.

I'm getting an error message (shown below) from the FTP server so the connection itself is established.
But it's the same error I'm getting if I try to connect without TLS1.2 so it seems that the proxy doesn't use TLS1.2 to connect to the FTP server.

What do I need to do to curl that curl "tells" the proxy to use TLS1.2?

Here the parameters and the log of the connection.

```
$ curl -v --tlsv1.2 -x http://login:password@mycompanyproxy.com:8080 --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (FM Scene 4.6.1)' ftp://login2:password2@ftp.tls.needed.ftpserver.com/
* About to connect() to proxy mycompanyproxy.com port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 1.2.3.4...
* Connected to mycompanyproxy.com (1.2.3.4) port 8080 (#0)
* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'login'
* Server auth using Basic with user 'login2'
> GET ftp://login2:password2@ftp.tls.needed.ftpserver.com/ HTTP/1.1
> Proxy-Authorization: Basic U1ZDLURFLUlQUy1XU1VTOlNhcHBoaXJlMQ==
> Authorization: Basic Z2VoZS1tcGZyOnRRenNjd0pxdzlISA==
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (FM Scene 4.6.1)
> Host: ftp.tls.needed.ftpserver.com:21
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="ftp.tls.needed.ftpserver.com"
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 157
< Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< X-BlueCoat-Authorization: 77988e24a55a2c1a=2EBFE78A00000002od75S6szNgteRTcwOqtLwkNggTT7RwAAAgAAAF/6EwOEAwAAAAAAAIOqMQAAAAAA
< Proxy-support: Session-based-authentication
< Date: Tue, 01 Jun 2021 13:04:57 GMT
<
Security Notice
You are about to access a secured resource. ftp.tls.needed.ftpserver.com
reserves the right to monitor and/or limit access to this resource at
* Connection #0 to host mycompanyproxy.com left intact
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Any `--tls*` settings given in curl are only relevant for the connections initiated by curl itself. With ftp access through a proxy the connection to the FTP server is done by the proxy, not by curl. This means the `--tls*` argument does not help.

> What do I need to do to curl that curl "tells" the proxy to use TLS1.2?

There is no way to instruct the proxy to use a specific TLS version to the FTP server. There is no way to instruct the proxy to use TLS at all with the FTP server. All what the proxy knows is that it should connect to a `ftp://...` URL. This is not specific to curl but how a HTTP proxy works.

> But it's the same error ...

There is no error shown at all. The output shows only the notice from the FTP server, i.e. the common welcome message send by a FTP server. It looks like you did not specify any file to retrieve in the URL. So all it does is connect to the FTP server, but not retrieve anything from it.